# Weird output of mysql union

Tags: mysql

```
<?php
$query120 = "(SELECT username FROM friendship WHERE frenusername='{$username2}') UNION (SELECT frenusername FROM friendship WHERE username='{$username2}')";
$result120 = mysql_query($query120,$connection) or die (mysql_error());
confirm_query($result120); 
while($userinfo120 = mysql_fetch_array($result120)){
    $frenusername2= $userinfo120['username'];
    echo $frenusername2;
}
?>
```

The output show the result of both select queries. Why `$frenusername2` has the value of `$userinfo120['username'];` and `$userinfo120['frenusername'];` both?

Comment: `$query120`? I seriously hope you don't have 120 different vars. Besides that, why aren't you using a wrapper for the database (PDO or something self-written) which does proper error handle. `or die(mysql_error())` is nothing proper.

Comment: I do have 120 different vars. LOL. I don't know how to do PDO although I have read lot about Prepare statement to avoid sql injection. Why or die(mysql_error()) is not proper?

Comment: Because it's lots of repeated code and you cannot even log the error or hide it from users' eyes. And about the 120 vars: Why not use the same one? You don't need to keep the old stuff.

Comment: Oh I see. I use jquery/ajax to fetch multiple php pages which have mysql query, I worry the query of pages are executed at the same time so conflict to each other... So better use different vars...When jquery/ajax is too fast, and previous mysql query didn't finish fetch data yet, it might conflict with current query... I not sure I am right or not? Maybe I just worry too much.

Comment: You are completely wrong. That kind of conflicts will never happen.

Comment: lol I just realize they won't conflict because the codes are executed on different pages. There is 100% sure no possible conflict by using the same variable for mysql right? If so, I will start using the same variable for them all... LOL.

Comment: what codes or way do you suggest me to replace or die(mysql_error())?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I'll bite, but you need more help than this site can give you. Perhaps a book or three on sql, mysql, and php...

To your question: sql `UNION` isn't doing what you think it's doing. When you send a `SELECT` sql query to a database, it returns 0 or more rows with the data you requested. Each row will have the number of columns specified in the `SELECT` clause of your statement (between the `SELECT` and the `FROM`).

In your query, you have only one column, `username`. When you use `UNION`, you (possibly) add more rows with the second query, but the column names don't change, so, assuming that the data in `friendship` looks like this:

```
username | frenusername
---------|-------------
usera    | userb
usera    | userc
userb    | userc
userc    | usera
```

and `$username2 = 'userb'`, then you'll get two rows that look like this:

```
username
--------
usera
userc
```

the first row being the result from

```
SELECT username FROM friendship WHERE frenusername='{$username2}'
```

and the second row being the result from

```
SELECT frenusername FROM friendship WHERE username='{$username2}'
```

If `$username2 = 'usera'`, you might be expecting a result like:

```
username
--------
userc
userb
userc
```

but `UNION` actually removes duplicates from the result set, giving

```
username
--------
userc
userb
```

See the [Mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html) for much, much more. In short, though, `UNION` is not necessarily the way to go when you want to get two separate data sets (one set of people who have `$username2` as a friend, and one set of people who `$username2` have as a friend).

As a bonus, unless you're including php pages inside other php pages (using [`include()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), etc), then you don't need to worry about using the same variable name just because the page is being accessed by the same AJAX script.

And yes, you should be worried about SQL injection if you use data directly from a POST or GET HTTP request. (i.e., if `$username2` is assigned from a value in `$_POST` or `$_GET` and you don't test it before the code you provide in your question)

Comment: I like your explanation about "UNION is not necessarily the way to go when you want to get two separate data sets". I guess UNION just combine two separate data sets into the field of 1st selection. That's why $frenusername2 holds both set of data. Thank you.